# Host frontpage via example.com and everything else via example.com/blog

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls, frontpage

I've assigned a page as frontpage which will be available via example.com.

All the other pages should be below the `/blog`.

For example:

```
Main-page: example.com
All posts: example.com/blog
Single Blog post: example.com/blog/my-blog-post
Category: example.com/blog/category/my-category
Tags: example.com/blog/tag/my-tag
```

Is this possible with WPs configurations?